# C# code converted from C++ not working

Tags: c#, c++

Consider the following C++ code which sends data over RS232 to a device.

```
  strcpy(m_MsgBytes, "SRT1");

  iTmp = finalizeNL20Message(m_MsgBytes, 4);

int CVTSSLTNL20Message::finalizeNL20Message(BYTE *pMsgData, int iInLen)
{
  BYTE ucMsg[MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH];

  ucMsg[0]  = MSG_STX; // 0x02
  ucMsg[1]  = NL20_BLOCK_ID; // ox01
  ucMsg[2]  = ATTR_CMD; // 'C'

  memcpy(&ucMsg[3], pMsgData, iInLen);

  ucMsg[3 + iInLen] = MSG_ETX;
  ucMsg[4 + iInLen] = calculateNL20Checksum(ucMsg, 4 + iInLen);
  ucMsg[5 + iInLen] = MSG_CR;
  ucMsg[6 + iInLen] = MSG_LF;

  memcpy(pMsgData, ucMsg, 7 + iInLen);

  return 7 + iInLen;
}

BYTE CVTSSLTNL20Message::calculateNL20Checksum(const BYTE *pData, int iInLen)
{
  BYTE ucChk = 0;

  for (int iCnt = 0; iCnt < iInLen; iCnt++)
    ucChk = ucChk ^ pData[iCnt];

 return ucChk;

}
```

I've rewritten this code in C# as the following:

```
public static string Generate()
{
    return RIONNLHelper.FinalizeMessage("SRT1");
}

public static string FinalizeMessage(string data)
{
    //STX=0x02 NL20BLOCKID=0x01 Command=C (Command from computer)
    data = "\x02\x01C" + data;

    //ETX=0x03 
    data += "\x03";
    data += (char)calculateNL20CheckSum(data);
    data += "\r\n";

    return data;
}

public static byte calculateNL20CheckSum(string data)
{
    byte chk = 0;

    foreach (byte b in Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data))
    {
        chk ^= b;
    }

    return chk;
}
```

And the string is converted to byte array before sending

bytes = data.Select(c=>(byte)c).ToArray();
Now the question is that the C# code never get a response from the device on these requests. It does send other data back so baudrate and all that is correct.

I have some doubts about the translation of the buffer from the C++ code. 0x020x01C data 0x03 checksum \r\n

became

\x02\x01C data \x03 checksum \r\n

Or else would the rewrite of the checksum calculation be correct? First calculation of checksum of the bytes and then converted back to char

Comment: Why are you working with `string` when you should work with a `byte[]`? (or at least a `List<byte>` or a `MemoryBuffer`)

Comment: Are you sure your checksum routine produces right value?

Comment: yes, same value in both C++ and C#

Comment: and Im using string because all other devices are implemented like that too. In the end the string gets converted to byte[] in one go

Comment: Strings in Windows and .NET are *Unicode*, UTF16 specifically. Using the 7-bit ASCII codepage will guarantee that non-English characters like those used in Western or Central Europe or Skandinavian countries will be converted to the wrong byte value or result in error characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an odd one. As always, I created a unit test. Then I built the C++ version using C++ CLR and got the test to compare output with your input "SRT1". Initially, it failed with

```
C++ version:  02 01 43 53 52 54 31 03 27 0d 0a 
C# version:   02 1c 53 52 54 31 03 79 0d 0a
```

That 1C looks rather familiar...

The error seems to be in the assumption that the string `"\x02\x01C" + data`; is the same as `"\x02" + "\x01" + "C" + data;` whereas the hex escape in will continue to be interpreting digits until it finds a character which is not a hex digit. So the 'C' becomes part of the hex escape.

Breaking up the literal allows the parser to parse the 'C' as a separate character, the unit test then passes.

Comment: you're right. This was an error in the original version forgot to update here. "\u01C" is one character, 01C hex, while "\u0001C" is two characters, STX and 'C'. Thanks for effort of course!

Answer (score 1):

Mmmh... Your problem is perhaps that some code uses `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(finalString)` to finally convert the `string` to `byte[]`, but the checksum could be >= 0x7F, so a non-ASCII character. Convert the `string` to `byte[]` manually after `Generate` like:

```
string result = Generate();
byte[] bytes = new byte[result.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
{
    bytes[i] = (byte)result[i];
}
```

and just to be sure change:

```
foreach (byte b in Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data))
{
    chk ^= b;
```

to

```
foreach (char ch in data)
{
    chk ^= (byte)ch;
```

Or you can use the `Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")` that maps values `0x00-0xFF` to unicode values `0x0000-0x00FF`.

as `Pete Kirkham` noted, unless you have some `data` with chars > `0x7F`, the checksum will be < 0x7F. This because the `^` operator will return 1 only with (1 ^ 0) or (0 ^ 1), so you must have the eight bit at 1 somewhere to have a checksum with the eight bit at 1.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think `var bytes = result.Cast<byte>().ToArray();` would also work and is pretty direct.

Comment: @chris Char is a Unicode character. It doesn't fit into a single byte. Casting to byte results in an InvalidCastException

Comment: @chris Yes... Sadly I'm a micro-optimizer, so I prefer to pre-size arrays... your call would generate a temporary copy of the array of bytes (in a private collection used internally by `ToArray`) and then it would become a `byte[]`, so two copies.

Comment: @xanatos try `"a".Cast<byte>().ToArray()` in Linqpad. It will throw. `Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes("å")` on the other hand will return `229`, the correct value. `Encoding.ASCII` will return 63, the `?` used for failed conversions

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, That's unfortunate. I expected the behaviour to be identical to `(byte)result[i]`: a plain cast to `byte` on each element.

Comment: @chris you are *truncating*. The code you posted results in mangled values. Strings in Windows and .NET use Unicode. Characters are *int*, not byte. You *can't* store the character in a single `byte`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Yet you can clearly cast each `char` element as in the answer and truncate it that way. I understand that each element is two bytes in UTF-16, but my failure was in thinking that `.Cast<byte>()` would do what the answer does under the hood.

Comment: @chris In general `Cast<>` doesn't work with value type to value type cast. For example `new int[1].Cast<long>().ToArray()` will throw an exception, but clearly an `int` can be upcasted to `long`.

Comment: @xanatos, Yeah, looking into it more, I think it's an unfortunate side effect of the boxing when `char` goes into generics where it tries to unbox a `char` straight to `byte` with the cast, while the answer already starts with an unboxed `char`.

Comment: This doesn't seem likely - you'd have to have non-ASCII values in the data for xoring it to set the high bit.